# Building a node.js chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, chat

I'm currently building a web chat with node.js for the backend. It uses web sockets for the communication between server and client. I haven't worked with node before and I always used PHP/MySQL and Ajax to store and retrieve data. The chat can be compared to MSN etc. with user accounts and contact lists.
I was looking for some tips and frameworks, which could help me with developing a website which heavily relies on JavaScript and which does all its communication via node.js.

- What would you recommend to store the data? Mongo db (mongoose? mongo-db native?), SQLite? An easy solution would be appreciated.
- Would you send everything via the websocket and would you establish a new connection for every conversation?
- Is there a way to get around PHP completely?
- Would you recommend the usage Backbone.js or Ember.js?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Pick something and see if it works out. If you have problems, come back and ask some real questions. Also, you should accept some answers to your previous questions.

Comment: "How should I design and implement _____ ?" is generally not a good form for a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Alright, I'll start building and come back when I have more concrete questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use mongo-db or couchDB to store the data.
- Establishing a new connection is better than sending everything through websockets and parsing them.
- Yes. Use node.js on the server side.
- You can try either one of them. Both have their pros & cons.

Answer (score 2):

> What would you recommend to store the data? Mongo db (mongoose?
>   mongo-db native?), SQLite? An easy solution would be appreciated.

I would suggest you to use [redis](http://redis.io), because it is [insanely fast](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks).

```
> Example of benchmark result The test was done with 50 simultaneous
> clients performing 100000 requests. The value SET and GET is a 256
> bytes string. The Linux box is running Linux 2.6, it's Xeon X3320 2.5
> GHz. Text executed using the loopback interface (127.0.0.1). Results:
> about 110000 SETs per second, about 81000 GETs per second.
```

As client I would use [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)

> Would you send everything via the websocket and would you establish a
>   new connection for every conversation?

websockets are not yet support by every browser(pointing especially to Internet Explorer ;)). I think you should use [socket.io](http://socket.io) which supports [multiple transports](http://socket.io/#browser-support) so that it will work in every major browser.

> Is there a way to get around PHP completely?

You could get around PHP completely. Use for example [express](http://expressjs.com/) as your web framework instead of PHP

> Would you recommend the usage Backbone.js or Ember.js?

Also need to have a better look at both of them.